# React-Native - iOS - disable manuel screen rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, rotation

i use the React-Native "[react-native-orientation"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation) - Library.

Is it possible, to disable Screenrotation by the User?
My App is the most time in Portrait mode. Some Views have a Landscape Orientation. Id like to disable the manuell rotation on Views with Portraitmode. I dont found a working way yet. Is it possible? If yes, how?

In xCode, i selected the Portrait, Landscape Left and Landscape Right-Mode. 
If i only check "Portrait", than the Views with Landscape do not work. So i checked all. But id like to disable manuell rotation by User.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, enabling all required rotation modes in the native configuration is necessary for the app to support rotating at all.

Custom rotation logic bound to a certain view is possible to add by using `Orientation.lockToPortrait()` and `Orientation.unlockAllOrientations()`. You probably want to bind these function calls to navigation actions or `componentWillUnmount` and similar component lifecycle events. API documentation: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#api.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried this out and it works.

When i leave the view in Portrait-Mode, i will remove the Listeners.
But my "componentWillUnmount" / "componentDidUnmount" doesnt called. Have you any idea why?

Comment: For example:
In my homeView i add a listener. If is landscape, i lock to Portrait. But when i change the view and the new view is in Landscape, the Listener is always there. But i will remove it, because i want to lock to landscape.

Comment: Not to portrait. How is it possible?

Comment: `componentWillUnmount` is correct, there's no lifecycle event called componentDidUnmount though. Might it be that `componentWillUnmount` is not in the correct view if it never gets called? Maybe try to place it in another view just to test out how that event works.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try it out tomorrow. But how can i remove listeners from view 'home' in my other view?

Comment: If you wish to enable landscape mode in only a few views, calling `unlockAllOrientations` when those views' container components mount and `lockToPortrait` when they unmount might do the trick. In that case you wouldn't need any listeners in the home view. If you wish to have listeners in the home view (assuming the home view is active in the background all the time), then you probably need some other logic to keep track of the currently active view. When the active view changes, you can lock or unlock orientation as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your time. My first solution was `unlockAllOrientations` and `lockToPortrait ` / `lockToLandscape`. But it doesnt worked. The mobile phone could still be rotated. So i added a listener. The Listener observe, if mobile Phone was rotated. If yes, than i do `lockToPortrait`. I do not know why it can still be rotated if i use unlock.. and `lockToPortrait`.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure that I'm able to help you further, would probably need to look at the actual use cases and context to figure out what is happening.